# Restlet error response format in JSON

Tags: java, json, restlet

Im using the [restlet](https://restlet.com/) framework to manager a projects API. It seems that by default error responses are formatted in HTML. How can I change that so that by default ALL error responses are in JSON format?

I've tried adding a custom converter which works great for the entity responses but not for error responses.

We have 110+ endpoints that support `application/json` so ideally I would like to just set the default errors to always return as JSON. The default converter works for all methods that return an actual entity.

```
@Get("json")
@Produces("application/json")
public User represent() {
    ...
    return result;
}
```

But the `ResourceException` thrown by this method returns HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure about the format your service is going to produce then you can annotate your service class with **@Produces** annotation at class level. Then you will not be required to define the same for each and every method.

Also, once **@Produces** is defined at class level and you want to change response format for a particular method then you can annotate that particular method for other format.

Try Below code..

```
public Response represent(){
try{

}catch(Exception ex){
    return Response.status(500)
            .entity(new ExceptionMessage("500", ex.getMessage()))
            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
            build();
}
return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(result).build();
```

}

And have below Model class for exception message.

```
@XmlRootElement
class ExceptionMessage{
    private String statusCode;
    private String errorMessage;

    public ExceptionMessage() {
    }

    public ExceptionMessage(String statusCode, String errorMessage) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }

    public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    public String getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }

    public void setStatusCode(String statusCode) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }

}
```

[This is the link dedicated to Restlet.](http://restlet.com/company/blog/2015/12/21/exception-handling-with-restlet-framework/)

Comment: This does not appear to work. The exceptions are still in HTML format.

Comment: Server Side exceptions are always going to be in HTML format. If you need to send JSON messages for exceptions then you need to handle exception in your methods and then create your own JSON string in catch block and send that to client.

Comment: That doesn't work. It just wraps the JSON error into an HTML error.

Comment: Are you basing this on actual Restlet knowledge or just generic WS implementation? It seems odd that a framework dedicated to WS APIs would not have a built in mechanism to control the error response format.

Comment: I had tried to simplified the implementation, yes it is based on generic WS implementation. You can follow http://restlet.com/company/blog/2015/12/21/exception-handling-with-restlet-framework/ for detailed information. We have to created exception handling classes in any case.

Comment: Your answer is technically correct. However, I ended up using the blog post you suggested to solve the issue using a `Status` handler classes for a couple of reasons. 1. I only had to write one class of 10 lines instead of  modifying 110+  method signatures. 2. Im generally not a fan of the generic `Response`, especially in our case as we need to make it clear what the response type is. Could you please add the blog link to your answer as the dedicated Restlet suggestion and Ill mark it as correct.

Comment: Dead Link. Archived Here: https://web.archive.org/web/20170406115031/http://restlet.com/company/blog/2015/12/21/exception-handling-with-restlet-framework/